# PyQt5: keep selection order with QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt5, qfiledialog, getopenfilename

I am writing a GUI where the user is asked to select multiple files to open. For this purpose I use QFileDialog. I need to keep track of the order in which the user selected the files, is it possible?

I have the following:

```
filepath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files(*.csv);;All Files (*)")
```

but the filepath contains the paths of the files, ordered as I found them in the folder, and not depending on the selction order. I know that I can ask the user to select a single file at a time, but with many files to open, it becomes cumbersome for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the static QFileDialog functions will show a native file-dialog. It seems that on your system, the native file-dialog automatically sorts the selected files (which may not be the case on all platforms). However, Qt's *built-in* file-dialog doesn't have this behaviour, so a simple fix would be to use that instead:

```
filepaths, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
    self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files(*.csv);;All Files (*)",
    options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
print('\n'.join(filepaths))
```

Example output:

```
/home/foo/tmp/mbe-issue.csv
/home/foo/tmp/data.csv
/home/foo/tmp/test.csv
/home/foo/tmp/category_list.csv
/home/foo/tmp/data2.csv
```

This behaviour isn't explicitly documented, but it works for me using both Qt-5.15.6 and Qt-6.4.0, so it appears to be a stable feature.